# How a function got passed to another function?

Tags: javascript, function

I came across a weird code which I didn't understood. It would be great if I get explanation.

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    action(array[i]);
  }
}

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;
forEach(numbers, function (number) {
  sum += number;
});
console.log(sum);
```

How the function got passed as parameter ? and how the inner function is getting that number.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_nested_functions.htm)

Answer (score 6):

In JavaScript, functions are what's called **first class citizens** (that's not necessarily true for other languages), that means that *functions can be treated as data*, you can pass functions as arguments, return functions from other functions, and create functions and assign them to variables.

Here's a very simple example:

```
function callWithoutParams(fn) {
  return fn(); // fn is the passed function.
}

let rand = callWithoutParams(Math.random); // Passing Math.random as a function.
callWithoutParams(() => console.log(42));  // Passing anonymous function
```

[`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) accepts a function as an argument, and *runs it on each element in the array*. So a simpler example is:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].forEach((element) => console.log(element)); // outputs 1-5 in order.
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, everything is an object, including `function`.

For simplicity, check this example:

```js
var func = function(number){
  console.log(number);
}

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

function foreach(data, callback){
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
    callback(data[i]);
  }
}

foreach(arr, func);
```

In JS, you can assign function to a variable. This is called as [Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function). So it acts as a normal variable, just that its type is object.

This allows us to pass function as a parameter.

Now your second question, **how the inner function is getting that number**.

in your code, `action(array[i]);` is passing value as a parameter, so

```
function (number) {
  sum += number;
}
```

here `number` is `array[i]`.